# How to figure out why a Eloquent model update method is returning FALSE

Tags: laravel-4

Running: "laravel/framework": "4.2.*"

In our project I have one particular model that is driving me nuts.  For many hours yesterday the following call returned false:

```
$model->update($attributes);
```

where $model is an instantiated Eloquent object.  Works fine for dozens of other models.  And I got it working, for a short while, by re-writing the model class.  Now it's broken again.  The update call is in a try catch block trapping PDOException as well as Exception, but nothing is thrown (at least I'm not catching anything), and I've dug into the Model.php class to see if I can see why it's failing there, but haven't been able to glean anything useful.

I've looked in my MySql & Apache log files -- nada.  And searching the web hasn't turned up anything useful.

Is there no way to find out from Laravel why update returns false?

Comment: For what it's worth in Eloquent/Model in the performUpdate method $this->fireModelEvent('updating') === false.  I've looked at that method and it's Greek to me.

Comment: If the Model event [(click here)](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#model-events) `updating` returns false the `update()` method will cancel and return false as well.